# JavaFX TableColumn.setCellFactory missing generic restrictions on OpenJDK8?

Tags: eclipse, generics, javafx, java

TableColumn.setCellFactory has the following signature:

```
public final void setCellFactory
(Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>> value) { cellFactory.set(value);}
```

Unexpectedly, this compiles:

```
myColumn.setCellFactory(x->{return "";});
```

And even this:

```
myColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<BigInteger, HashMap>()
    {
        @Override public HashMap call(BigInteger big)
        {return new HashMap();}
    });
```

At runtime, I then get a ClassCastException, however I expect this to be caught at compile time. Eclipse however shows the signature just as "callback" without the generic restrictions. What is the problem here, is it Eclipse, or JavaFX or OpenJDK and how can I properly get the compile error in this case?

I use Eclipse Luna with OpenJDK 1.8.0-45 and installed JavaFX on Arch Linux.

P.S.: The following correctly gives me two compile errors:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

class Test
{
    static void picky(List<String> stringList)  {}

    static void reallyPicky(List<List<String>> stringListList) {}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        picky(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        reallyPicky(new ArrayList<List<Integer>>());
    }
}
```

Comment: what type is myColumn? Like `TableColumn<HashMap, BigInteger>`?

Comment: This just seems weird. The [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/dc75acb38de7/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.java) definitely requires a `Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>>`.  This looks more like a problem with your compiler than anything: you don't have some strange compiler setting enabled in Eclipse?

Comment: myColumn is of type TableColumn.  I don't think it is a fault of my compiler because using other types I correctly get compile errors (see my edit above).